# PostgreSQL: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, aws

First, I've searched for and found several posts relating to this error, and most of them point either to a RAM issue or an SSL issue, I tried overcoming the SSL possibility by adding the sslmode=disabled in the command line:

```
 psql -U waypoint -d waypoint -W -c "alter table telemetria_data.historico alter clase type smallint, alter valor type real[], alter power type smallint, alter voltaje type real;" -h localhost -v sslmode=disable
```

But the same message appeared:

```
SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
connection to server was lost
```

Regarding the possible memory issue, I don't know how to troubleshoot it.

The data structure is the one described in [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174574/postgresql-database-re-design-considerations) question and, as you may found this would a very long running query to complete achieve the full alter table over all the inherited tables.

OS:

```
Linux ip-10-1-0-9 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

PostgreSQL:

```
PostgreSQL 9.4.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit
```

**Update 2017-06-01 13:50 GMT**

Changed command to (due to @ Daniel Vérité 's recommendations):

```
time PGSSLMODE=disable psql -U waypoint -d waypoint -W -c "alter table telemetria_data.historico alter clase type smallint, alter valor type real[], alter power type smallint, alter voltaje type real;" -h localhost
```

Problem actually changed to the following:

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
connection to server was lost
```

**Update 2017-06-01 15:34 GMT**

Found several log entries (in `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log`) like these:

```
2017-06-01 13:48:49 UTC [22899-357] LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (19 seconds apart)
2017-06-01 13:48:49 UTC [22899-358] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
```

So I'll proceed with the suggested hint.

Also found this group of entries, that actually refer to the crash and later recovery:

```
2017-06-01 13:49:04 UTC [4982-17] LOG:  server process (PID 6569) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
2017-06-01 13:49:04 UTC [4982-18] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: alter table telemetria_data.historico alter clase type smallint, alter valor type real[], alter power type smallint, alter voltaje type real;
2017-06-01 13:49:04 UTC [4982-19] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2017-06-01 13:49:04 UTC [22902-2] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2017-06-01 13:49:04 UTC [22902-3] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2017-06-01 13:49:04 UTC [22902-4] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2017-06-01 13:49:04 UTC [16383-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:04 UTC [16384-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:04 UTC [16386-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:04 UTC [16385-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:04 UTC [4982-20] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2017-06-01 13:49:05 UTC [16402-1] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-06-01 13:48:45 UTC
2017-06-01 13:49:05 UTC [16403-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:05 UTC [16404-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:05 UTC [16414-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:05 UTC [16415-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:06 UTC [16452-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:06 UTC [16453-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:06 UTC [16462-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:06 UTC [16463-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:06 UTC [16472-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:06 UTC [16473-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:06 UTC [16482-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:06 UTC [16483-1] waypoint@waypoint FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-01 13:49:09 UTC [16402-2] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2017-06-01 13:49:09 UTC [16402-3] LOG:  redo starts at 11EC/9960F440
2017-06-01 13:49:21 UTC [16402-4] LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 11E6/52726000 in log segment 00000001000011EC000000C9, offset 7495680
2017-06-01 13:49:21 UTC [16402-5] LOG:  redo done at 11EC/C9723D60
2017-06-01 13:49:32 UTC [16402-6] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2017-06-01 13:49:32 UTC [4982-21] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Any suggestions on this last log part?

OOM Killer is enabled, and the following is the output at `/var/log/messages`:

```
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.672817] psql invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x2000d0, order=2, oom_score_adj=0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.675652] psql cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.677274] CPU: 1 PID: 16367 Comm: psql Not tainted 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680406] Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.2.amazon 11/11/2016
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  0000000000000000 ffffffff815123b5 ffff88003dcda1d0 0000000000000000
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  ffffffff8150ff8d 0000000000000000 ffffffff810d6e3f 0000000000000000
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  ffffffff81516d2e 0000000000000200 ffffffff810689d3 ffffffff810c43e4
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557] Call Trace:
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff815123b5>] ? dump_stack+0x5d/0x78
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff8150ff8d>] ? dump_header+0x76/0x1e8
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff810d6e3f>] ? smp_call_function_single+0x5f/0xa0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff81516d2e>] ? mutex_lock+0xe/0x2a
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff810689d3>] ? put_online_cpus+0x23/0x80
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff810c43e4>] ? rcu_oom_notify+0xc4/0xe0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff81153d1c>] ? do_try_to_free_pages+0x4ac/0x520
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff811427dd>] ? oom_kill_process+0x21d/0x370
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff8114239d>] ? find_lock_task_mm+0x3d/0x90
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff81142f43>] ? out_of_memory+0x473/0x4b0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff81148e0f>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x9ef/0xb50
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff81065c86>] ? copy_process.part.25+0x116/0x1c50
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffffa00f6bba>] ? call_filldir+0x9a/0x160 [ext4]
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff81058301>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1d1/0x4f0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff811ac3f9>] ? get_empty_filp+0xc9/0x1c0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff81067990>] ? do_fork+0xe0/0x3d0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff811c6a1c>] ? __alloc_fd+0x7c/0x120
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff815188f9>] ? stub_clone+0x69/0x90
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.680557]  [<ffffffff8151858d>] ? system_call_fast_compare_end+0x10/0x15
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.734210] Mem-Info:
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.735151] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.736512] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.738300] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.740072] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.741335] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.743092] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.745210] active_anon:370484 inactive_anon:549110 isolated_anon:24
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.745210]  active_file:240 inactive_file:1425 isolated_file:0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.745210]  unevictable:0 dirty:173 writeback:0 unstable:0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.745210]  free:20427 slab_reclaimable:9729 slab_unreclaimable:3425
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.745210]  mapped:567547 shmem:587500 pagetables:4209 bounce:0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.745210]  free_cma:0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.760872] Node 0 DMA free:15224kB min:184kB low:228kB high:276kB active_anon:228kB inactive_anon:188kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15988kB managed:15904kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:144kB shmem:204kB slab_reclaimable:4kB slab_unreclaimable:80kB kernel_stack:80kB pagetables:4kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.777646] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3757 3757 3757
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.779553] Node 0 DMA32 free:69956kB min:44868kB low:56084kB high:67300kB active_anon:1481708kB inactive_anon:2196252kB active_file:1772kB inactive_file:1748kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):96kB isolated(file):0kB present:3915776kB managed:3849676kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:2267676kB shmem:2349796kB slab_reclaimable:38712kB slab_unreclaimable:13620kB kernel_stack:2032kB pagetables:16832kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:14 all_unreclaimable? no
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.795757] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.797650] Node 0 DMA: 11*4kB (EM) 8*8kB (EM) 1*16kB (E) 2*32kB (UE) 1*64kB (E) 1*128kB (E) 2*256kB (UE) 2*512kB (EM) 3*1024kB (UEM) 3*2048kB (EMR) 1*4096kB (M) = 15228kB
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.804011] Node 0 DMA32: 13752*4kB (UEM) 85*8kB (EM) 54*16kB (M) 43*32kB (M) 17*64kB (M) 15*128kB (M) 10*256kB (M) 3*512kB (M) 2*1024kB (M) 0*2048kB 1*4096kB (R) = 71176kB
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.811528] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.815461] 588017 total pagecache pages
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.816967] 0 pages in swap cache
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.818205] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.820215] Free swap  = 0kB
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.821475] Total swap = 0kB
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.822543] 982941 pages RAM
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.823640] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.825110] 16525 pages reserved
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.826310] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.827473] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.830523] [  159]     0   159     8242      800      21        0             0 systemd-journal
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.833717] [  162]     0   162    10200      135      22        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.836679] [  316]     0   316     6351     1726      14        0             0 dhclient
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.839533] [  351]     0   351     7181       72      18        0             0 cron
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.842112] [  353]     0   353     4964       68      14        0             0 systemd-logind
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.844894] [  362]   107   362    10531       96      26        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.847504] [  376]   106   376     8345      154      21        0             0 ntpd
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.850085] [  377]     0   377    65721      457      30        0             0 rsyslogd
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.852755] [  388]     0   388     3909       39      12        0             0 agetty
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.855305] [  389]     0   389     3864       40      13        0             0 agetty
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.857914] [  451]     0   451    13796      168      29        0         -1000 sshd
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.860562] [  481]  1002   481    26362     5081      54        0             0 perfmon_loop.rb
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.863918] [  486]  1002   486    15211     3146      31        0             0 cht_perfmon
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.867273] [  625]     0   625     9560      144      22        0             0 master
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.869878] [  630]   108   630    10164      234      24        0             0 qmgr
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.872356] [ 3443]     0  3443    20130      213      41        0             0 sshd
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.874903] [ 3445]  1000  3445    20164      222      39        0             0 sshd
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.877451] [ 3446]  1000  3446     3176       43       9        0             0 sftp-server
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.880261] [ 4982]   105  4982   614831    42946     132        0          -900 postgres
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.882988] [ 6634]     0  6634     1570       23       9        0             0 collectdmon
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.885784] [ 6635]     0  6635   174485      156      36        0             0 collectd
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.888347] [22899]   105 22899   615399   541666    1105        0             0 postgres
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.890970] [22900]   105 22900   615395    14251      88        0             0 postgres
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.893836] [22901]   105 22901   615088     4252      53        0             0 postgres
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.896365] [22902]   105 22902   615305     1316      60        0             0 postgres
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.899083] [22903]   105 22903    21336      378      40        0             0 postgres
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.901954] [ 2946]   108  2946    10076      137      22        0             0 pickup
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.904462] [ 6376]     0  6376    20130      213      42        0             0 sshd
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.907440] [ 6378]  1000  6378    20130      209      40        0             0 sshd
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.910534] [ 6379]  1000  6379     5795      151      16        0             0 bash
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.913144] [ 6382]     0  6382    11515      107      28        0             0 sudo
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.915635] [ 6383]     0  6383    11895       96      27        0             0 su
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.918149] [ 6384]   105  6384     5796      139      16        0             0 bash
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.920900] [ 6561]   105  6561    18289      236      40        0             0 psql
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.923394] [ 6569]   105  6569   925161   853454    1718        0             0 postgres
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.926097] [16319]     0 16319    10865       95      25        0             0 cron
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.928611] [16320]     0 16320    10865       95      25        0             0 cron
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.931063] [16321]     0 16321    10865       95      25        0             0 cron
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.933758] [16322]     0 16322    10865       95      25        0             0 cron
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.936197] [16323]  1000 16323     1084       20       7        0             0 sh
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.938762] [16324]  1000 16324     1084       20       7        0             0 sh
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.941450] [16325]  1000 16325     1084       21       7        0             0 sh
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.943849] [16326]  1000 16326     1084       21       6        0             0 sh
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.946409] [16327]  1000 16327     3612       54      12        0             0 telemetria.sh
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.949258] [16328]  1000 16328     3613       57      12        0             0 instantaneo.sh
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.952633] [16329]  1000 16329    21335     4808      48        0             0 mon-put-instanc
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.955744] [16330]  1000 16330     3612       54      12        0             0 conexiones.sh
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.958555] [16366]  1000 16366    10744     1513      26        0             0 psql
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.961216] [16367]  1000 16367    10735     1512      26        0             0 psql
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.963722] [16368]  1000 16368     7725     1044      19        0             0 aws
```

**Update 2017-06-01 16:19 GMT**

Changed settings to:

```
checkpoint_segments = 100       # in logfile segments, min 1, 16MB each
checkpoint_timeout = 30s        # range 30s-1h
```

And I filled the hard drive :( I generously increased the checkpoint_segments, but didn't first check the available space. Luckily I'm testing this procedure in a non-production environment. So I may have to clone the production server once again, or is there any way to free up temp space used, that's now being wasted?

```
ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16384/3940428": No space left on device
HINT:  Check free disk space.
```

As per @deszo's question, the memory overcommit values are the following:

```
vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0
vm.overcommit_kbytes = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 0
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
```

**Update 2017-06-01 18:107 GMT**

Server instance is an AWS c4.large (2 vCPU, 3.75GB RAM)

A few more parameters `from postgresql.conf`:

```
shared_buffers = 2GB            # min 128kB
work_mem = 32MB             # min 64kB
max_connections =800            # (change requires restart)
```

Comment: Looks like a backend crash. It might be an out of memory condition. Check the postgresql server logs, and if the OS is Linux and the OOM killer is enabled, the kernel logs at the time of the failure.

Comment: @DanielVérité added PostgreSQL and kernel log entries to the question

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT - apart from this, what is the RAM size on your instance?  What are `shared_buffers`, `work_mem`, and `max_connections` set to?

Comment: @dezso added...will have to follow your link's tips, but once I "resurrect" the instance from de disk full issue ;)

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that you're running PostgreSQL on AWS. If so, you need to identify this in the question and the tags.

The last process mentioned in the kernel dump is in fact `aws` so it seems like a safe bet

```
Jun  1 13:49:04 ip-10-1-0-9 kernel: [260956.963722] [16368]  1000 16368     7725     1044      19        0             0 aws
```

With regard to PostgreSQL, this just implies [a connection failure](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/21447.1342710083%40sss.pgh.pa.us)

As far as trouble shooting it what is triggering aws's oom_killer, you have two options..

- Lower [`work_mem`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html) below the threshold that triggers oom_killer. Whatever query gets planned differently around the difference in memory or is slower is the one that is holding you up.
- Set [`log_statement`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) and read the last queries issues before the out of memory crash.